# What is the right cookie format for subdomains cookies

Tags: java, http, cookies, browser

I'm developing an application, where there are a number of subdomains, for example api.*.com, which is responsible for REST request processing. I'm trying to set cookie for subdomains, using:

```
public class PlayerTokenUtils {

    final private static int DEFAULT_AGE = (int) TimeUnit.DAYS.toSeconds(7);

    private PlayerTokenUtils() {
        throw new IllegalAccessError();
    }

    public static PlayerToken updateResponse(String token, HttpServletResponse response) {
        Cookie cookie = new Cookie("player", token);
        cookie.setPath("/");
        cookie.setHttpOnly(true);
        cookie.setDomain(".mavarazy.com");
        cookie.setMaxAge(DEFAULT_AGE);
        response.addCookie(cookie);
        return token;
    }
}
```

I see in Firebug, that everything works fine for registration Request (http://api.mavarazy.com:3333/registration/base/signin) & Response contains:

```
Set-Cookie  player=rHIHtISWzw; Domain=.mavarazy.com; Expires=Sun, 02-Nov-2014 07:44:54 GMT; Path=/; HttpOnly
```

But further requests to the server with api.mavarazy.com do not contain player Cookie, returned from Set.

The environment for testing, that I'm using:

I modified my /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1       mavarazy.com
127.0.0.1       api.mavarazy.com
```

My REST server is running Tomcat.

All REST requests for the browser go through Node.js proxy.

**What am I doing wrong? What is the right format for player Cookie in this case?**

Comment: Could you elaborate on "do not contain player Cookie, returned from Set"? WHat do you mean by that? How do you check if the cookie is sent?

Comment: By looking at requests in firebug, they do not have player Cookie in them.

Answer (score 0):

I've found an issue with jQuery configuration in my Backbone application.

Adding

```
$.ajaxSetup {
    ...
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    }
    ...
}
```

Solved the problem.